# How to make a stats count with a if-condition to specific value on the log

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm newbie with Splunk and I'm trying make a query to count how many requests have a determinate value, but this counter must be incremented if a specific attribute is on the request.

Example:

```
2020-01-09 13:51:28,802 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-8] class:ControllerV1, UA=[tokyo], GW=[api-gateway-id]
2020-01-09 13:51:31,865 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-9] class:ControllerV1, UA=[tokyo], GW=[api-gateway-id]
2020-01-09 13:51:32,922 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-10] class:ControllerV1, UA=[tokyo], GW=[api-gateway-id]
2020-01-09 13:51:36,939 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-2] class:ControllerV1, UA=[tokyo], GW=null
2020-01-09 13:51:48,614 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] class:ControllerV1, UA=[new-york], GW=[api-gateway-id]
2020-01-09 13:51:49,266 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-3] class:ControllerV1, UA=[new-york], GW=[api-gateway-id]
2020-01-09 13:51:57,533 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-4] class:ControllerV1, UA=[helsing], GW=[api-gateway-id]
```

For the example above, I must increment the counter if `GW != null`, so I've three counters, for **tokyo**, **new-york** and **helsing**. The results should be something like:

```
tokyo | new-york | helsing
  3   |    2     |    1
```

Tried:

`source="/logfiles.log" | rex "UA=(?<user-agent>\w+)" | stats count(eval(user-agent="[tokyo]")) as TOKYO`

But returns the error: `Error in 'rex' command: Encountered the following error while compiling the regex 'UA=(?<user-agent>\w+)': Regex: syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator).`

I know that can't use `-` but I must do it and when I remove it, the results keeping null (0 results).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `NOT "GW=null"` in your base search , if  field GW is being evaluated then you can add  `GW!=null`

This is how, I have seen regex syntax  ( use field name if the message is evaluated in some field or use *raw), also changed the hiphen(-) to underscore(*) variable name  as the variable name with '-' are not accepted.

```
source="/logfiles.log" 
| rex field=_raw "UA=(?<user_agent>\w+)" 
| stats count(eval(user-agent="[tokyo]")) as TOKYO
```

But in the above regex also, you need to be considerable of the square braces '['
so below regex should work

```
 source="/logfiles.log" 
| rex field=_raw "UA=(?<user_agent>\[\w+\])" 
| stats count(eval(user-agent="[tokyo]")) as TOKYO
```

Comment: How I use NOT `"GW=null"` on the query?

Comment: This NOT is part of the seach, so type like source="/logfiles.log" NOT “GW=null” | rex field=_raw "UA=(?<user_agent>\w+)" | stats count(eval(user_agent="[tokyo]")) as TOKYO